Why block catch() doesn't catch error, when I use "for await" cycle
The block catch(err){} in promiseAll function doesn't catch error.
const promiseAll = async (promises) => {
  const result = [];

  try {
    for await (let element of promises) {
      result.push(element);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  return result;
};

const result = promiseAll([
  Promise.resolve(1),
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3);
    }, 3000);
  }),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject(2),
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3);
    }, 1000);
  }),
]);

result
  .then((data) => console.log("Data", data))
  .catch((err) => console.log("err", err));

The block catch(err){} in promiseAll function doesn't catch error.
For me interesting why I can't catch the error in block catch. What is the solution ?

how do you know? your catch simply throws the error it caught - the catch block definitely get entered though - if all you are going to do in a catch block is re-throw the error, there's no point in try/catch at all to be honest

You shouldn't really use for await with an array of promises. It's for consuming async iterables. for await of VS Promise.all

I believe what your seeing is the fact your not awaiting the rejected promise immediately,  Chrome debugger then detects this during next tick as been a dangling promise,  and why you get the extra error in the console.    You can prevent this extra error by attaching a dummy catch before your awat's -> for (let element of promises) { element.catch(e => {}); }  Not something I suggest doing that often, but to prevent this extra error it will work.

@JaromandaX  I think the OP is referring to the extra unhandled error, the error is indeed caught, it's just the Browsers unhandled promise rejection kicks in, and you could say creates a false positive.. :)

I get that this is just for an example, but please please pretty please don't reject a Promise with a value that isn't an Error.

@JaredSmith Totally agree, I think this is one of the reasons Javascript exceptions sometimes get a bad name, been using Zig and having errors as values I feel like it's a step backwards, regardless of what theprimeagen believes..

@Keith TBF I prefer errors-as-values with sum types (e.g. Result in Rust). Some just swing that way lol

@JaredSmith  Skill issue,, .. (only joking).. :)

@Keith I literally lol'd, nice way to start a Friday

Because you have not attached any error handling catch callbacks to your error, and you allow extra event loops (ticks) to fire, Chrome will see this as an unhanded promise rejection error.
One solution to just simply attach a catch callback to all the elements before awaiting them.
Example below, the only downside is that it will only report the first error it finds, but you could handle that issue too if it required.


const promiseAll = async (promises) => {
  const result = [];
  //were awaiting promises, let attach dummy catch
  //so that next tick doesn't detect error as unhandled.
  for (let element of promises) element.catch(e => {});
  //Don't worry the error we just swallowed above
  //will resurface during the await
  for (let element of promises) {
    result.push(await element);
  }
  return result;
};

const result = promiseAll([
  Promise.resolve(1),
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3);
    }, 3000);
  }),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject(2),
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(3);
    }, 1000);
  }),
]);

result
  .then((data) => console.log("Data", data))
  .catch((err) => console.log("err", err));



